# Plastics dataset (US)

Tags: data-request, usa, environment

I'm looking for any type of plastics data in the US. Is there a dataset around the waste or use of plastic materials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [www.quandl.com](https://www.quandl.com) and search for "plastic united states" in the search bar at the top left corner. The results will show several free databases with plastics data from databases like the *US Census Bureau* which shows data on the imports or exports of plastic materials, or the *United Nations Industrial Development Organization* which shows data on employees and outputs in the plastics industry, or the *US Energy Information Administration* which shows manufacturing data for plastic products. Hope this helps in some way. [Disclosure: I work for Quandl]